# Python: how do I create a list of combinations from a series of ranges of numbers

Tags: python

For a list of numerical values of n length, e. g. `[1, 3, 1, 2, ...]`, I would like to create a list of the lists of all possible combinations of values from `range[x+1]` where x is a value from the list. The output might look something like this:

```
for list[1, 3, 2] return all possible lists of range[x+1] values:
    # the sequence of the list is unimportant
[
[0,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,2,0],[0,3,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2],[1,1,0],
[1,2,0],[1,3,0],[1,0,1],[1,0,2],[0,1,1],[0,2,1],[0,3,1],[0,1,2],
[0,2,2],[0,3,2],[1,1,1],[1,2,1],[1,3,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,2],[1,3,2]
]
```

So in this example I am looking for all variations of `[e1, e2, e3]` from `e1 in [0,1], e2 in [0,1,2,3] and e3 in [0,1,2]`

Comment: What is `x` in your example? Lists of length `x=3`?

Comment: @Yuval see added comment in question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `itertools.product` with a dynamically-specified list of iterators:

```
vals = [1,3,2]
for item in itertools.product(*[range(x+1) for x in vals]):
    print item
```

Output:

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 2, 0)
(0, 2, 1)
(0, 2, 2)
(0, 3, 0)
(0, 3, 1)
(0, 3, 2)
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 0, 2)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 0)
(1, 2, 1)
(1, 2, 2)
(1, 3, 0)
(1, 3, 1)
(1, 3, 2)
```

Comment: On a quick scan, this appears my favorite! All of them are great. Also, this example makes it easy for me to see how to turn this into a lambda function as well.

Answer (score 5):

Python's itertools module has a tool that does what you need:

```
import itertools
p = itertools.permutations([0, 1, 2, 3])
p_as_list = list(p)
```

Edit: As your needs are fairly specific you could benefit from having your own function that does something alike this one: (note I haven't got the implementation down just yet, maybe someone might refine this):

```
def magic_permutations (*args):
    lists = []
    larg = len(args)
    for i in range(larg):
        lists.append([])
    i = 0
    for nums in args: 
        for num in nums:
            if i >= larg:
                i = 0
            lists[i].append(num)
            i += 1
    return lists
```

Edit: I misunderstood your question the first time, so I'll apologize for that. I'll however leave this be.

Comment: Doesn't give the desired answer. If `p = itertools.permutations([1,3,2])`, `len(list(p))` is only 6.

Comment: I now understand what you mean, except I am stuck with the implementation.

Comment: I'm not sure why this got so many upvotes; it's just wrong. You got the right module, but the wrong function.

Answer (score 3):

To obtain the exact sequence shown in the question (albeit in a different order, but that's not a problem) use this function:

```
import itertools as it

def combs(lst):
    return [list(e) for e in it.product(*(range(x+1) for x in lst))]
```

The result is as expected:

```
combs([1, 3, 2])

=> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2],
    [0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 1], [0, 2, 2], [0, 3, 0], [0, 3, 1], [0, 3, 2],
    [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2],
    [1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2], [1, 3, 0], [1, 3, 1], [1, 3, 2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for ii in itertools.product(range(2),range(4),range(3):
    print ii
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 2, 0)
(0, 2, 1)
(0, 2, 2)
(0, 3, 0)
(0, 3, 1)
(0, 3, 2)
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 0, 2)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 0)
(1, 2, 1)
(1, 2, 2)
(1, 3, 0)
(1, 3, 1)
(1, 3, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not in the same order, but I think this is what you wanted:

```
def xrangeCombinations(input):
    if len(input) > 1:
        for i in xrange(input[-1] + 1):
            for j in xrangeCombinations(input[:-1]):
                yield j + [i]
    else:
        for i in xrange(input[-1] + 1):
            yield [i]

for i in xrangeCombinations([1, 3, 2]):
    print i
```

Produces the output:

```
[0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 0]
[0, 2, 0]
[1, 2, 0]
[0, 3, 0]
[1, 3, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
[0, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[0, 3, 1]
[1, 3, 1]
[0, 0, 2]
[1, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 2]
[0, 3, 2]
[1, 3, 2]
```

This solution might be slower than alternatives so if speed is an issue you should probably improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy` if you don't mind getting tuples in the end:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> e1=np.array([0,1])
>>> e2=np.array([0,1,2])
>>> e3=np.array([0,1,2,3])
>>> g=np.meshgrid(e1,e2,e3) #you need numpy ver>1.7.0, change the order of final result by changing the order of e1, e2, e3
>>> zip(*[item.flatten() for item in g])
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 3), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (0, 2, 3), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3)]
```